# Javascript fetch and console.log json giving undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

inside body of html::

```
<button class="getUsers">get users</button>
```

JS::

```
const getUsers = () = > {
  fetch("users.json")
    .then((res) = > {
      res.json()
    })
    .then((data) = > {
      console.log(data);
    })
}
document.querySelector(".getUsers").addEventListener("click", getUsers)
```

users.json::

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Rick",
  "email": "rick@gmail.com"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "maria",
  "email": "maria@gmail.com"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "gadnjaman",
  "email": "gadnjaman@gmail.com"
}]
```

My question is why do I get undefined, when clicking the button and how do i fix it?

Comment: You need to return something from the first `then()`

Comment: `res.json()` -> `return res.json()`

Comment: `.then(res => res.json())`

Comment: @Hammerbot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `json()` here like:

```
const getUsers = () = > {
  fetch("users.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Here:

```
res => res.json()
// equivalent to: (res) => { return res.json(); }
```

or you can use async/await like:

```
const getUsers = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("users.json");
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

DEMO:

```js
const getUsers = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}

getUsers();
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Arrow functions MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   explicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   return statement.

So, as said in the comments, either (block body):

```
.then((res) = > {
  return res.json()
})
```

or (concise body):

```
.then(res => res.json())
```